# Multiple serial monitors with the same arduino mega

Tags: serial

I’ve got mega 2560.
In my project serial port is used for communicating with PC.
However, I’d like to see debug info in serial monitor. Mega has a few hardware Serial ports. How to use one of them got extra serial monitor?

Answer (score 2):

Use an USB to TTL Serial adapter. Wire it to one of the RX/TX pin pairs and in code use the corresponding Serial object Serial1, Serial2 or Serial3. Don't forget to wire Ground.

You can use some terminal program or Serial Monitor in Arduino IDE to communicate over the adapter. You can open a second instance of the Arduino IDE by starting it with the Desktop or menu shortcut. In this instance you can select a different port then the sketch upload port.

[image]

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/57653/can-i-have-two-separated-serial-monitor-for-the-same-arduino-board-connected-to/57669

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect one (or more) to your PC. To do that you would use a USB to TTL UART adaptor, like an FT232 board.

That will give you a new COM port that you can open with your terminal program of choice, though opening the Arduino "serial monitor" multiple times might be somewhat difficult.